# Best way to remove duplicates from a vector in java

Tags: java

I'm thinking about following:

// remove duplicates from a vector in java

First sort the elements of the vector of any fast sorting algorithm, e.g. Quicksort. This costs O (nlogn). Duplicates will then be adjacent each other. Go through the sorted vector and remove the duplicates. This costs O (n). Total cost: O (nlogn).

Is not it better to do this instead:

adding all the elements of the vector in a HashSet

empty vector

adding all of the elements from the HashSet to the vector

Total cost will be: O (n) because of adding from HashSet to the vector

Thinking I right?
Thanks

Comment: Yes if you can use HashSet, TreeSet would also give NlogN.

Comment: @John why nlogn ?thanks

Comment: @KrkroMrmro Using a `TreeSet` would be `O(nlogn)` because insertion in a `TreeSet` is `O(logn)`. On the other side, if you use a `HashSet` insertion is `O(1)`, which would give `O(n)` for `n` elements.

Comment: Because TreeSet sorts on insert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.

You get improved big O regarding runtime. Of course, you pay for that on the memory side, as you end up with a vector and that set.

When using a LinkedHashSet you even keep the order from your initial vector.

And finally: you should prefer list / ArrayList over the old school vector class.

Comment: John says it is nlogn ,, see above please

Comment: When using TreeSet you would be sorting while inserting! Set is only cheaper when no sorting takes place!

Comment: GhostCat yes that is why I did edit my post and wrote hashSet as mentioned above